# Selecting columns and rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here i am trying to count the times a police office is present (a 1 value (2 and 3 mean not present)) at an accident and if there is more chance they are present on a weekday or at the weekend. So far i have out my data into day of the week i now need to select the 1 values and compare them if anyone hows ho to do this. The code i have used and pandas dataframe is below;

```
#first we need to modify the date so we can find days of the week
accidents['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(accidents['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
accidents.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], inplace=True)

#now we can assign days of the week
accidents['day'] = accidents['Date'].dt.strftime('%A')

#now we can count the number of police at each day of the week
accidents.value_counts(['Did_Police_Officer_Attend_Scene_of_Accident','day'])
```

What im looking for in this bottom like is something like; accidents.value_counts(['Did_Police_Officer_Attend_Scene_of_Accident','day'] ==1) but im unsure how to write it

data preview;

```
  Accident_Index       Location_Easting_OSGR Location_Northing Did_Police_Officer_Attend_Scene_of_Accident   day
  2019320634369        521429.0              21973.0                  1  Tuesday
  2019320634368        521429.0              21970.0                  2  Tuesday
  2019320634367        521429.0              21972.0                  1  Wednesday
  2019320634366        521429.0              21972.0                  3  Sunday
  2019320634366        521429.0              21971.0                  1  Sunday
  2019320634365        521429.0              21975.0                  2  Monday
```

Update, desired outcome.
So here is the code i had from all of the attended accidents. I now wish to do this again but split into weekdays and weekends

```
 #when did an officer attend
 attended = (accidents.Did_Police_Officer_Attend_Scene_of_Accident == 1).sum()
```

This bit of code now need to include the weekday (then another with weekend) before calling.sum

My desired output would be similar to this but would also count the weekday and weekend values, preferably returned in 2 dataframes. This would then allow me to compare the weekday to the weekend dataframe allowing me to return an single value for each of which has more officers attending

Comment: which is the input and which is the desired output?

Comment: Yeh sorry that wasn't too clear, so this is all the input. I'm looking to return a dataframe of just the times a police officer attended an event, which here we is a 1. Once this has been found i need to compare the times an officer attended an accident against the unattended events in both the weekdays and weekends. Hopefully thats a bit clearer.

Comment: could you include the desired output for this sample as well?

Comment: Updated in the question. Not sure that will help you too much as im just looking for a final output as a value after comparing each. Basically Attended vs not attended in the week and the same again at the weekend. This will then allow me so see which is better attended

Comment: You could first split into two dataframes: `weekends = accidents[accidents["day"].isin(["Saturday", "Sunday"])]`, `weekdays = accidents[~accidents["day"].isin(["Saturday", "Sunday"])]`.  Then carry on as you were.